# Scala private method/function vs nested method/function

Tags: scala

When would one define a method/function with the private modifier in a class as opposed to nesting it within the principal calling method/function? Is there a performance hit when nesting functions?

Comment: Either the function is use as oneshop lambda, or it's used privately from many place.

Comment: Seems what you are looking for is answered pretty well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482326/the-cost-of-nested-methods

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you're App is less performant when using nested functions since they are moved to class level during compilation ([The cost of nested methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482326/the-cost-of-nested-methods)). But it helps you to have the smallest scope as possible, which is a good class design.

So if no other method is using your def, it is a good idea to define it as a nested function.